Should we have a "question-a-thon"?
It would be great if we could get our question rate higher (currently we are on 1.6 questions / day)
I thought we might have an event where each of us contribute one quality question per day for a month?
How hard is it to create a new badge? We could award a one-off badge to users who successfully submit one question per day for the whole month. "Beta Booster"?
We should probably also "require" that the questions be of reasonable quality - perhaps the question should have a minimum of +2 votes. We don't want to encourage spammy nonsense.

It's good that users want to help the site, so I applaud to your effort here but there are buts:

Encouraging voting as the measure for winning might make people have their friends vote for them or even their "side" accounts... So a less controllable measurement should be pursued (visits?).
A new badge is more or less out of the question, not because it's abad idea, but because it's nearly impossible that the devs would just develop a new badge for a single site or even for all sites just for this need. Unfortunately we cannot promise prizes and maybe it's for the best, since that would make people just post whatever stuff just to get it.

Some sites have made such things many times always without prizes and why couldn't we do it too?

I agree about not encouraging meaningless voting. I wasn't thinking so much of having one winner.. more of a "we all win" collaboration.  But yeah it doesn't have to have a prize / reward, we can just have an event to get the question rate higher.

@trideceth12 Ah I see. :D Yes. :)

I would suggest that you provide some kind of theme to prompt people's questions. Something like the Chinese New Year challenge from last year. Perhaps a different theme each week for a month?
